Rewound Ziel fan 1ph 4 pole motor
4 pole, single ph, variable PSC fan motor.
I rewound the motor and now it draws 3 amps. Its only supposed to draw 1 amp. I'm sure I have the connection right. But I had to go half a wire size bigger because I don't have half size wire. And I may be out 3 or 4 turns on the coils. What did I do wrong.
